# FOR XML Could Not Serialize the data for node NoName - Can't Replace XML Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm using SQL Server 2014, I'm  trying to remove XML characters from data in a table and I am successful for most of the XML characters. But I have an issue with this character:  0xDE7B

I have a T-SQL statement that includes a STUFF function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.[Doc#],
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ltrim(rtrim(a.[MyColumn]))
           FROM #temp th
           WHERE a.[Doc#] = b.[Doc#]
           GROUP BY ltrim(rtrim(a.[MyColumn]))
           FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') [MyColumn]
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 547
>   FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0xDE7B) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

But when I do the following:

```
REPLACE([MyColumn], CHAR(0xDE7B), '')
```

this ends up NULLING out ALL the values in that column. I have a function that removes all other XML characters (i.e., 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002...) and it appears to be working for them.

Comment: OK, so first of all... With regards to your `REPLACE`, it's important to note that 0xde7b is clearly a unicode character so you would need to use `NCHAR` and not `CHAR`. `CHAR(0xde7b)` is NULL but `NCHAR(0xde7b)` isn't. As per [`REPLACE` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql), `REPLACE` returns `NULL` if any one of its arguments are `NULL`. Also note that even using `NCHAR`, if your strings are full of unicode characters, certain collations will treat a LOT of unicode characters as being the same even if they're actually different.

Comment: As far as using FOR XML PATH(''), obviously it doesn't like unicode characters ("illegal" characters). I'm not sure how useful it is to you to replace all the unicode characters in your strings and still concatenate the result... It might be wise to tackle this from another angle if you really need to concatenate them all in a single column for whatever reason. For example, using a recursive query might perform worse but would negate the necessity of having to replace unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you ZLK.  I updated my table with the replace function (using nchar instead of char) the values are not NULLED out, but I STILL get the same error.  So I guess it didn't work.  i would imagine the error message would be a different one?

Comment: When you say it produces the same error, which one is that? The one with `0xDE7B`? If so, I don't see how that's possible unless the table didn't update properly. FYI, I just ran a test on a table that contains every unicode character and running a similar stuff query after running a replace produced an error for a different character code but not the same one.

Comment: Yes, same 0xDE7B error.  Updated the table for all fields with this (EX):  set [Author] = replace([Author], nchar(0xDE7B), '')

Comment: I can't even think of how that would be possible unless there's another table somewhere in that query that you're accidentally doing something with. I can't see how it's actually possible to produce that error if the character doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely bizarre.  But that is EXACTLY what's going on.  Should the for xml path be changed from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR?

Answer (score 6):

The character in question is the �

You should not try to use your own replace logic to get rid of forbidden characters. There are far to many possible candidates. Even if this would work, tomorrow you might get a new one, you did not think about... XML is doing this for you implicitly. Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT 'This inlcudes forbidden characters like < & > and your �' AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''));
```

The result wil be "`This inlcudes forbidden characters like &lt; &amp; &gt; and your ?`"

The engine obviously uses a simple question mark instead of the �. The reason is the missing `N`, so your string is taken as `VARCHAR` (=ASCII). Just try the same with a leading `N` to get your special characters back:

```
SELECT (SELECT N'This inlcudes forbidden characters like < & > and your �' AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''));
```

You can use this in your code like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.[Doc#],
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ltrim(rtrim((SELECT a.[MyColumn] AS [*] FOR XML Path('')))) --<-- a.MyColumn should be NVARCHAR(X)
           FROM #temp th
           WHERE a.[Doc#] = b.[Doc#]
           GROUP BY ltrim(rtrim((SELECT a.[MyColumn] AS [*] FOR XML Path(''))))
           FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') [MyColumn]
```

Make sure never to let any `VARCHAR` interfer. All involved columns and all involved steps (functions (!)) must accept `NVARCHAR` and return `NVARCHAR`

Therefore I changed the return type of your final `.value()` to `nvarchar(max)` too.

Comment: Shnugo:  Interesting, thank you.  Will try this shortly and report back.

Comment: This works when I remove the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.  The syntax as you've provided produces the error:  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Column 'MyColumn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Craig the column's expression must be the same in the group by... You might use a sub-select to address it by name